# Why back/cancel click result doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I have a problem using camera in my app.

When app is opened, in ImageView - "no_photo" image.

When I click on the picture, camera opens with using intent.

If I get image, app worked perfectly. But if I click "back" or "cancel", my code doesn't work. 
I need to set "no_photo" image on ImageView, but in result I have empty page.

I have tried various methods, but they doesn't work too:

```
setImageResource();
setImageDrawable();
```

This code call the camera:

```
CamPRW.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        MainPageActivity.fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MainPageActivity.fileUri); // set the image file name

        //  start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
});
```

OnActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == MainPageActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            CamPRW.setImageURI(MainPageActivity.fileUri);
            CamPRW.setScaleX(-1.0f);
        } else{
            CamPRW.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_photo));
        }

    }
```

P.S.
I have tried with "RESULT_CANCELED" code, but it doesn't work too

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == MainPageActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                CamPRW.setImageURI(MainPageActivity.fileUri);
                CamPRW.setScaleX(-1.0f);
            }
            if (resultCode == MainPageActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                CamPRW.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_photo));
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: at the time of back/cancel u need to send request code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. It's my mistake. I forgot that the variable state checking in onResume. Now it works with old code. Thanks. The issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think `onActivityResult` on getting call on back/cancel button 
Add `code snippet` on back/cancel button click. Add pass value whatever you want and handle in `onActivityResult`

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle .putString(key, value);
  Intent i = getIntent(); //gets the intent that called this intent
  i.putExtras(bundle);
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
  finish();
```